# How I get a @NamedQuery Query with WERE Command in Java EE?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, javabeans

hi i have a java ee application and I want to create a Query to get all Tickets from a User.

I have a Ticket class, TicketDAO Interface and TicketBean class
I have a User class, UserDAO interface and UserBean class

Here is my User class:

```
  @Entity
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name=User.QUERY_GETALL,query="SELECT c FROM User c"),
        @NamedQuery(name=User.QUERY_GETALLTICKETS,query="SELECT c FROM Ticket c ...????"),
    })
    public class User implements Serializable{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static final String QUERY_GETALL = "User.GetAll";

        public static final String QUERY_GETALLTICKETS = "User.GetAllTickets";
...
```

here is my UserBean class:

```
@Override
public List<Ticket> getAllUserTickets() {

    return em.createNamedQuery(User.QUERY_GETALLTICKETS,Ticket.class).getResultList();
}
```

My Ticket Table have the column username.

Answer (score 0):

Move QUERY_GETALLTICKETS from the User class to the Ticket class; then you can write something like:

> @NamedQuery(name=Ticket.QUERY_GETALLTICKETS,query="SELECT t FROM     Ticket t where t.userName = :" + P_USER)

Declare P_USER as:

> public final static String P_USER = "pUser";

Then you can use the query this way:

> @Override
>   public List getAllUserTickets(String username) {
>
> Query query =     em.createNamedQuery(Ticket.QUERY_GETALLTICKETS,Ticket.class);
>   query.setParameter(Ticket.P_USER, username);
>
> return query.getResultList();
>   }